# Is it possible to make rules in Azure like you can do in AWS WAF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, ip-address, amazon-waf

I'm planning to move the development environment from AWS to Azure, 
and I'm researching on how to make rules in Azure like I made rules in AWS WAF.

In AWS WAF, I made a rule with 2 conditions. 
a) When a request originates from certain IP addresses
and
b) When a request matches at least one of the filters in the string match condition
  (This includes body contains xxx or query string contains xxx)

Is it possible to do the same thing in Azure as well?

Answer (score 0):

We can create Network Security Groups(NSG) and attach them(one or more) a Virtual Machine NIC(s) or the Subnet itself in Azure. You can create rules on NSG to allow or deny inbound or outbound network traffic based on source or destination IP address, port, and protocol.

More Info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview

Comment: Thanks for the information.
By further research, I found out using CDN is also possible.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine-reference-match-conditions